# New member with performance question

Tags: 14.04, performance

Just loaded Ubuntu on an older PC and it seems to be running very slow and “choppy”.

I am running ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my 2003 Compaq Presario S4000NX.

- RAM = 993MB
- Processor = Intel Celeron 2.40GHz
- Graphics = on board Intel 845Gx86/MMX/SSE2
- OS = 32bit
- Hard Disk = 156GB

Am I under powered for this version? Would I be better off trying to install a graphics card or using a different version of Linix? I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: you can try k/l/xubuntu and see for yourself =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try LXDE I installed LXDE on an older laptop with similar specs. as yours, and it flys. Ubuntu was my 1st choice, but the machine, esp. the graphics wasn't man enough...